# Why are the build folders empty after running cmake command?

Tags: cmake, makefile, gtkmm

I am trying to follow the [tutorial](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/gtkmm/UsingCMake#write_the_CMakeLists.txt) but I can't figure out why my `build_debug` and `build_release` are empty and nothing is compiled when I run the `cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug ../` followed by `make`

and I am trying to compile the following

```
#include <gtkmm.h>
int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    auto app = Gtk::Application::create("org.gtkmm.example");
    return 0;
}
```

as for the contents of the parent `CMakeLists.txt`

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.26)
project(exmaple)
find_package(PkgConfig)
pkg_check_modules(GTKMM gtkmm-4.0)
add_subdirectory(src)
```

and the child `CMakelists.txt` in `src`

```
link_directories(
    ${GTKMM_LIBRARY_DIRS}  )

include_directories(
    ${GTKMM_INCLUDE_DIRS}  )

add_executable(app
    main.cpp)

target_link_libraries(app 
    ${GTKMM_LIBRARIES}  )
```

after running `cmake -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug ../` both build folders are empty. The directory tree looks like this:

```
.
├── build_debug
├── build_release
├── CMakeCache.txt
├── CMakeFiles
│   ├── 3.26.1
│   │   ├── CMakeCCompiler.cmake
│   │   ├── CMakeCXXCompiler.cmake
│   │   ├── CMakeDetermineCompilerABI_C.bin
│   │   ├── CMakeDetermineCompilerABI_CXX.bin
│   │   ├── CMakeSystem.cmake
│   │   ├── CompilerIdC
│   │   │   ├── a.out
│   │   │   ├── CMakeCCompilerId.c
│   │   │   └── tmp
│   │   └── CompilerIdCXX
│   │       ├── a.out
│   │       ├── CMakeCXXCompilerId.cpp
│   │       └── tmp
│   ├── app.dir
│   │   ├── build.make
│   │   ├── cmake_clean.cmake
│   │   ├── compiler_depend.internal
│   │   ├── compiler_depend.make
│   │   ├── compiler_depend.ts
│   │   ├── DependInfo.cmake
│   │   ├── depend.make
│   │   ├── flags.make
│   │   ├── link.txt
│   │   ├── progress.make
│   │   └── src
│   │       ├── main.cpp.o
│   │       └── main.cpp.o.d
│   ├── cmake.check_cache
│   ├── CMakeConfigureLog.yaml
│   ├── CMakeDirectoryInformation.cmake
│   ├── Makefile2
│   ├── Makefile.cmake
│   ├── pkgRedirects
│   ├── progress.marks
│   └── TargetDirectories.txt
├── cmake_install.cmake
├── CMakeLists.txt
├── Makefile
└── src
    ├── app
    ├── CMakeFiles
    │   ├── app.dir
    │   │   ├── build.make
    │   │   ├── cmake_clean.cmake
    │   │   ├── compiler_depend.make
    │   │   ├── compiler_depend.ts
    │   │   ├── DependInfo.cmake
    │   │   ├── depend.make
    │   │   ├── flags.make
    │   │   ├── link.txt
    │   │   ├── main.cpp.o
    │   │   ├── main.cpp.o.d
    │   │   └── progress.make
    │   ├── CMakeDirectoryInformation.cmake
    │   └── progress.marks
    ├── cmake_install.cmake
    ├── CMakeLists.txt
    ├── main.cpp
    └── Makefile

15 directories, 50 files
```

Comment: Having file `CMakeCache.txt` in the **source** directory means that you have performed **in-source** build. While that file exists in the source directory, CMake will always force in-source build whenever you call `cmake`. For make out-of-source build remove `CMakeCache.txt` from the source directory.

Comment: ... and then perform the build steps, starting with the `cmake` command, somewhere other than the root of the source tree.

Comment: Basically, it's not possible in cmake to have both _in-source_ and _out-of-source_ builds at the same time with the same source directory.  If you want to use out-of-source builds then you can have as many as you want but **all** your builds must be out-of-source.  If you want to use in-source builds, then you can have only that one in-source build.  And, if you want to switch from in-source to out-of-source then ALL the CMake-generated files (like CMakeCache.txt) must be cleaned up from the in-source build before you can start the out-of-source build.

Comment: BTW, at the very end of the output CMake **prints** the exact directory where build files are created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did an in-source build instead of an out-of-source build. You can specify where the build directory should be using [the `-B` flag](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#cmdoption-cmake-B) of the generate command, and the source directory using [the `-S` flag](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#cmdoption-cmake-S) of the generate command.

Here's the table from the docs describing what happens if you specify none, some, or all of those flags:

> | Command Line | Source Dir | Build Dir |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | `cmake src` | `src` | *cwd* |
> | `cmake build` (existing) | *loaded* | `build` |
> | `cmake -S src` | `src` | *cwd* |
> | `cmake -S src build` | `src` | `build` |
> | `cmake -S src -B build` | `src` | `build` |
> | `cmake -B build` | *cwd* | `build` |
> | `cmake -B build src` | `src` | `build` |
> | `cmake -B build -S src` | `src` | `build` |

Seeing that you pre-created `build_debug/` and `build_release/`, and that you're using `-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=...`, [which is only for single-config generators](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE.html), what you probably meant to do was something along the lines of the following (with the current working directory being the root directory of your project (the one containing `src/`)):

```
cmake -S . -B build_debug -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug ...
cmake -S . -B build_release -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release ...
```